# Prove that this limit equals $5f'(x)$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x-3h)}{h} =5f'(x)$$

From the basic form $f(x+h)-f(x)$ I used $x-3h$ as $x$ and $x+2h$ as $x+h$
and used this to make the question like this.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I've added [our preferred formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). Note in particular a derivative uses an apostrophe, not a backtick.

Comment: Hint:$$\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x-3h)}{h}=2\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{2h}+3\frac{f(x-3h)-f(x)}{-3h}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative is the slope of the tangent line, which is the limiting value of slopes of secant lines as two points converge on the graph of the function. With a bit of manipulation, we can make your limit look like such a limit.

If you consider the secant line connecting points on the graph above $x-3h$ and $x+2h$, the slope is
$$
\frac{f(x+2h) - f(x-3h)}{(x+2h) - (x-3h)} 
= \frac{f(x+2h) - f(x-3h)}{5h}
= \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{f(x+2h) - f(x-3h)}{h}.
$$
Now, notice that as $h \to 0$, each of $x-3h \to x$ and $x+2h \to x$, and the difference $5h \to 0$ as well, so
\begin{align} 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+2h) - f(x-3h)}{h} 
&= 5 \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+2h) - f(x-3h)}{5h} \\[3pt]
&= 5 \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+2h) - f(x-3h)}{(x+2h) - (x-3h)} \\
&= 5 \cdot f'(x)
\end{align}

Comment: Crystal clear.  +1

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x-3h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)+f(x)-f(x-3h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{h}-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-3h)-f(x)}{h}$

Consider $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Let $h=\frac{t}{2}$, then $t\to 0$ as $h\to 0$:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{\frac{t}{2}}=2\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}=2f'(x)$$

Similarly $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-3h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Let $h=-\frac{t}{3}$, then $t\to 0$ as $h\to 0$:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-3h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{-\frac{t}{3}}=-3\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}=-3f'(x)$$

Thus, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{h}-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-3h)-f(x)}{h}=2f'(x)-(-3f'(x))=5f'(x)$.